# Ensuring Parse has performed inBackground operation before continuing code

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to make as a backend for an Android app. I have several "inBackground" related functions that need to happen consecutively and then send the results back to my Activity which I use to build a ListView. I am looking for a "clean" way to do this, such as writing a class with methods to call from my Activity. I can't figure out how to do this in an external class though. Take the following code for example:

```
List<ParseObject> list = ParseUtility.getList();
```

We will define getList() as something like

```
private List<ParseObject> result;

public List<ParseObejct> getList() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo(KEY, VALUE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                result = list;
            } else {
                result = null;
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

I believe that the "findInBackground" would cause this method to return before "result" is set to the correct value. What is a workaround to this?

Comment: Have you tried putting the return statement inside the callback? What happens if instead of result = list, you put return list (and return null)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get result from your function you have to use 'synchronized' method ParseQuery.find(...) instead of 'asynchronous' ParseQuery.findInBackground(...). And then call this function from a worker thread or service or AsyncTask, etc...

```
public static List<ParseObejct> getList() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TABLE_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo(KEY, VALUE);
    result = query.find();
}


 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ParseObject>>() {

   @Override
   protected List<ParseObject> doInBackground(Void... params)
   {
       return ParseUtility.getList();
   }
 }.execute();
```